# Specflow not passing table

Tags: specflow

I've just started playing around with Specflow, Watin and Deleporter.

I am having a problem with an integration type test, in that it wont pass the table data into the corresponding test.

```
Scenario: User tries to register and their email already exists
Given I have filled out the register page with the following data
| Name | Password  | Nickname     | Email           |
| Sam  | password1 | SamsNickname | email@email.com |
When I already have an account with the same email
| Name | Password  | Nickname     | Email           |
| Sam  | password1 | SamsNickname | email@email.com |
Then Show message that the account exists


[Given(@"I have filled out the register page with the following data")]
public void GivenIHaveFilledOutTheRegisterPageWithTheFollowingData(Table table)
{
    var data = table.Rows.First();

}
```

The problem I am having is the Table parameter above is passed in as null. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I'm not able to repro your issue in a new project with specflow 1.8.1 and Nunit and reshaper as the testrunner. Table is not null and contains the values from the scenario. Can you post some more context? Or can you try to repro the issue in a new project?

Comment: I've downloaded the Guestbook example by Steve Sanderson on GitHub and run one of his tests, I get the table being passed in as null as well.   I too am using Nunit and Resharper

Comment: To initiate my test, on the test above, a right click and click go TestWith->Debugger. This is correct isnt it?

Comment: Turns out I was debugging within the individual specflow test. So it had no context or knowledge of the specflow table. You need to run the the whole specflow feature from Resharper (in debug mode) this then runs the tests associated with the Specsflow feature. Nunit console allows you to run the tests associated with a feature, but not debug them.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong runner executes your test.

Go to the following option:
Tools -> Options -> Specflow -> General -> Test Runner Tool

Change the value to "Auto" or "SpecRun"